# Как в vitest js сравнить структуру двух объектов

Tags: javascript, тестирование, vite

Допустим у меня есть два объекта:

```
const karp = {
    name: "kl",
    age: 18,
  };
  const cazan = {
    name: "kl",
    age: 17,
  };
```

Я хочу сравнить объекты по структуре.
Как это сделать в vitest js

Comment: Там есть метод `toMatchObject` https://github.com/GizmoDevDev/vitest-tescting/blob/main/docs/basic-knowledge.md

Comment: Нет toMatchObject также сравнивает и значения, то есть он выдаст исключение т.к. в одном объекте age: 18, а в другом age: 17. Мне же нужен метод сравнивающий только структуру, необращающий внимание на значения

Comment: Если нужно сравнить список ключей - можно получить массивы с ключами `Object.keys(obj)` и уже сравнивать массивы...